# What if the Docker installed image does not have a shutdown command?

Tags: docker, wsl-2

The official image `ubuntu18.04` of the installed `Docker`

```
PS C:\Users\17293> docker images
REPOSITORY   TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED       SIZE
ubuntu       18.04     4eb8f7c43909   2 weeks ago   63.1MB
PS C:\Users\17293> docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND   CREATED       STATUS       PORTS     NAMES
12910e0535ad   ubuntu:18.04   "bash"    2 hours ago   Up 2 hours             mineos
```

I tried `poweroff`, `shutdown` and `halt`, but how can I `shutdown`?

```sh
root@12910e0535ad:/# uname -a
Linux 12910e0535ad 5.4.72-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Wed Oct 28 23:40:43 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@12910e0535ad:/# poweroff
bash: poweroff: command not found
root@12910e0535ad:/# shutdown
bash: shutdown: command not found
root@12910e0535ad:/# halt
bash: halt: command not found
root@12910e0535ad:/#
```

Comment: [`docker stop my_container`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stop/)?

Comment: If the command was just an interactive bash shell, `exit` from within that shell should also exit it.

Comment: If you actually wanted to shutdown the Docker host OS itself, containers are not normally allowed to do that (for good reasons).

Answer (score 0):

From the host you can use `stop`:

```
docker stop container_ip/name
```

From the container itself, if you have an interactive command line, use `exit`